# How to resolve a list of hostnames to ip addresses while querying dig or using getent

Tags: bash, dig, resolve

I need to resolve all "A" records for a domain to ip addresses if they exist while creating a bash script.

I've looked to see if there was a dig command to retrieve all a records for a domain but could not find any, so I am using the hostnames that I know exist from a visual that is given to us by a particular online chat program.

This is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash

pricks=(
   "c1.domain.com"
   "c2.domain.com"
   "c3.domain.com"
   "c4.domain.com"
   "c5.domain.com"
   "c6.domain.com"
   "c7.domain.com"
   "c8.domain.com"
   "c9.domain.com"
   "c10.domain.com"
   "c11.domain.com"
   "c12.domain.com"
   "c13.domain.com"
   "c14.domain.com"
   "c15.domain.com"
   "c16.domain.com"
   "c17.domain.com"
   "c18.domain.com"
   "c19.domain.com"
   "c20.domain.com"
)

for prick in "${pricks[@]}"
do
   echo "apf -d $prick \"$prick\"" >> add_apf_rules.sh
done
exit
```

This gives me the following output which I can easily execute and which will add the hostnames to the apf deny hosts file ...

```
apf -d c1.domain.com "c1.domain.com"
apf -d c2.domain.com "c2.domain.com"
apf -d c3.domain.com "c3.domain.com"
apf -d c4.domain.com "c4.domain.com"
apf -d c5.domain.com "c5.domain.com"
apf -d c6.domain.com "c6.domain.com"
apf -d c7.domain.com "c7.domain.com"
apf -d c8.domain.com "c8.domain.com"
apf -d c9.domain.com "c9.domain.com"
apf -d c10.domain.com "c10.domain.com"
apf -d c11.domain.com "c11.domain.com"
apf -d c12.domain.com "c12.domain.com"
apf -d c13.domain.com "c13.domain.com"
apf -d c14.domain.com "c14.domain.com"
apf -d c15.domain.com "c15.domain.com"
apf -d c16.domain.com "c16.domain.com"
apf -d c17.domain.com "c17.domain.com"
apf -d c18.domain.com "c18.domain.com"
apf -d c19.domain.com "c19.domain.com"
apf -d c20.domain.com "c20.domain.com"
```

Hostnames are not allowed in the "/etc/apf/deny_hosts.rules" so I need a way to resolve the hostname to an ip, if it exists, and place the ip instead of the hostname.

How can I use getent to accomplish my task?

```
getent hosts c15.domain.com | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem: is it about querying all A records from zone domain.com or resolving a (known) list of domain names?

Comment: I was not able to find a command to query all A records so I was showing what I have come up with. I am very open to suggestions and whatever way works best is what I will use. I am not sure I am on the right track but I know for sure I am not too far off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `host -l domain.com` or `dig domain.com AXFR` (they both do the same thing) but it's very likely forbidden by owner of DNS server for security reasons.

If it is, then there is no way to retrieve all A records.

EDIT: I can not understand what are you asking for, so I start guessing:

Q: How can I alter my first script in order to get result:

```
apf -d 66.96.162.92 "c1.domain.com"
apf -d 66.96.162.93 "c2.domain.com"
apf -d 66.96.162.94 "c3.domain.com"
```

A:

```
for prick in "${pricks[@]}"; do
   echo apf -d $(getent hosts "$prick") >> add_apf_rules.sh
done
```

Comment: You are actually telling me something I already knew and stated. Please read the ending part of my post which states very clearly what I am trying to do.

Comment: I still don't understand your question, because it already contains the answer

Comment: This works well. As long as you know the hostnames, this was perfect.